# RAM Utilization in Windows 10/Windows 11

Tags: windows-10, memory, windows-11, dell-latitude, intel-core-i7

I have Core i7 6th Generation Dell Latitude Laptop with 16GB RAM, while if I check via Task Manager, I see that only 6GB maximum getting utlized (if I total-up the Memory column sum), and still the Task Manager is showing 80% Memory used. So where is rest 10GB gone (16GB - 6GB = 10GB)?

I recently upgraded to Windows 11 Pro Dev version from Windows 10 Pro. The RAM consumption was little less in Windows 10, as I remember it was around 65% with the similar usage as I am doing currently. So the issue was even earlier in Windows 10 too, as where was the rest RAM was going but now in Windows 11 it is more-more gap. Any clues how to fix the issue?

[image]

My System **About** Information:

[image]

Other Screenshots to Identify the issue:

[image]
[image]
[image]

RAMMap Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: This question gets asked a lot.  Same answer all the time. Windows uses the memory it needs and for a 64-bit system, 4 to 6 GB is quite normal.

Comment: You do understand that your processor isn't supported by Windows 11? I suspect if you view the Performance tab and click on Memory you will get a clearer picture of what's actually happening.  RAMMAP also does a better job of giving you insight into memory usage. What's not being shown in your screenshot the memory that is immediately available and what's actively being used[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1699920/).  I don't see anything that is wrong with your system based on the screenshots you have provided.

Comment: Here are those screenshots: https://i.imgur.com/Jnq0LbX.png and https://i.imgur.com/Dhe1iuL.png and https://i.imgur.com/rdDoiHQ.png and RAMMap Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/bo4rt9m.png RAMMap shows something "Process Private" is using around 7.2 GB of RAM. Can I stop that?

Comment: @John: in my case, Windows is using around 7 to 8GB

Comment: This post addresses the core of the question "why does memory usage not match the sum of totals listed:" https://superuser.com/questions/906161/why-do-resource-monitor-and-task-managers-total-ram-usage-not-even-remotely-add

Comment: Side note: your rammap screencap is confusing to me. Number grouping (commas): "1,15,82,680" is an odd way of presenting decimal numbers.

Comment: @Yorik, you are right, that is quite odd. but then again, as a yank, I've never understood thousand-millions either. localization sometimes has odd effects on the expression of numbers.